# Convert numeric to specific date format in R

Tags: r, date-formatting

I am trying to convert a numeric column "DATE" to date column "NEW_DATE" in format YYYYMM:

```
DATE        NEW_DATE
1.2020      202001
```

I have tried `as.Date` but it returns the following error:

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

The structure function says that the column is num so not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `zoo`'s `as.yearmon` and then convert it with `format`.

```
format(zoo::as.yearmon('1.2020', "%m.%Y"), "%Y%m")
#[1] "202001"
```

So for the dataframe, we can do :

```
df$NEW_DATE <- format(zoo::as.yearmon(df$DATE, "%m.%Y"), "%Y%m")
```

Or in base R we can paste an arbitrary date and convert to date.

```
df$NEW_DATE <- format(as.Date(paste0(df$DATE, ".1") "%m.%Y.%d"), "%Y%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Isolate the month: 

date_month <- gsub("\\..*", "", df$DATE)

# Store the NEW_DATE  vector in desired format: 

df$NEW_DATE <- paste0(gsub(".*\\.", "", df$DATE),
               ifelse(nchar(date_month) == 1, paste0("0", date_month), date_month))

# Data: 

df <- data.frame(DATE = "1.2020", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```